# Google cloud pub/sub subscription durability?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been reading about Google Cloud Pub/Sub on their website, and it looks like a messaging solution that I have implemented, but I would consider moving to it so that my team does not have to maintain that code base.  One detail that I have not seen the answer to, so far, is regarding the durability of subscriptions, topics, etc, after service restarts.  I have probably missed it, and I am sure that this question must be answered somewhere, but if someone could point me to that information, I would be grateful.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for that.  I missed it.  Do you know what mechanism is used to persist this information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Google Cloud Pub/Sub [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#persistent):

> **Are messages durable or persistent if the subscriber is not present?**
>
> Yes. The Pub/Sub system guarantees that subscriptions retain
> unacknowledged messages in persistent storage for 7 days from the
> moment they were published. In addition, note that subscriptions whose
> client presence has not been detected for 30 days may be automatically
> deleted. For example, if messages are pulled within 30 days of the
> last Pull operation, this has the effect of restarting the 30 day
> clock for the subscription deletion; however, any messages published
> before 7 days may be lost regardless of their acknowledgment state.

**UPDATE:**

Now you can go to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#resource_limits), in the Subscription section:
[image]

Thanks to @dxps for the update!

Comment: Nowadays, we can still find such reference in https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#resource_limits